# How to check if a record is in an approval process in validation rule?

Tags: validation-rule, approval-process

I know it can be done in apex, but is there any way to check if a record is in an approval process in validation rule ?

Comment: "Record is in approval process in validation rule"?

Comment: If something like Approval.isLocked(recordId); can be used in validation rule ?

Comment: Nope. I don't think so.

Comment: i will go with a trigger then. I think i will be able to use Approval class there.

Comment: [Adding a checkbox field that you set in the approval process](http://sfdcsrini.blogspot.com/2014/07/how-to-check-whether-record-has-been.html) seems to be the common recommendation if you want to stick with a validation rule.

Comment: i think using a trigger with Approval class be cleaner solution.

Comment: Better recommendation is try it through APEX itself.